# Manipulação de xml tratar strings como se fossem arquivos

Tags: python, xml

Estou recebendo um `xml` no formato de `string` no meu response. Eu quero manipular esse `xml` e gerar uma lista das tags `<item>` do xml retornado pelo web service. Aqui vai o trecho do meu código:

```
if (op == 2):

    print '\n'*3
    print 'TESTE Viagem'; sleep(2);
    print '\n'*3

    response = oRodov.viagem() #xml

    tree = ET.parse(response)
    root = tree.getroot()
    iterador = root.getiterator()
    for x in iterador:
        if x.tag == "item":
            print x.items()
```

O código esta me retornando um `IOError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rodoviario.py", line 134, in ?
    tree = ET.parse(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/elementtree/ElementTree.py", line 1120, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/elementtree/ElementTree.py", line 642, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>\n\n<viagem origem="1" destino="2" data="2014-07-02" servico="2311" grupo="DEMON">\n <saida dia="0" hora="02:00" />\n <chegada dia="0" hora="12:15" />\n <empresa>DEMON</empresa>\n <mensagem-servico></mensagem-servico>\n <destino>2</destino>\n <moeda>R$</moeda>\n <preco>51.10</preco>\n <layout>\n  <secao nome="Unica">\n   <item x="0" y="0">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="01" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="1" y="0">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="05" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="2" y="0">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="09" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="3" y="0">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="13" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="4" y="0">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="17" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="5" y="0">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="21" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="6" y="0">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="25" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="7" y="0">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="29" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="8" y="0">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="33" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="9" y="0">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="37" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="10" y="0">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="42" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="0" y="1">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="02" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="1" y="1">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="06" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="2" y="1">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="10" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="3" y="1">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="14" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="4" y="1">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="18" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="5" y="1">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="22" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="6" y="1">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="26" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="7" y="1">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="30" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="8" y="1">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="34" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="9" y="1">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="38" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="10" y="1">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="41" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="12" y="2">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="04" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="1" y="3">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="08" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="2" y="3">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="12" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="3" y="3">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="16" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="4" y="3">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="20" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="5" y="3">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="24" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="6" y="3">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="28" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="7" y="3">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="32" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="8" y="3">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="36" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="9" y="3">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="40" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="10" y="3">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="44" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="0" y="4">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="03" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="1" y="4">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="07" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="2" y="4">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="11" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="3" y="4">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="15" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="4" y="4">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="19" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="5" y="4">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="23" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="6" y="4">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="27" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="7" y="4">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="31" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="8" y="4">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="35" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="9" y="4">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="39" />\n   </item>\n   <item x="10" y="4">\n    <assento ocupado="0" tipo=" " numero="43" />\n   </item>\n  </secao>\n </layout>\n</viagem>\n'
```

Identifiquei que esse erro esta acontecendo por que eu não estou informando um diretório de arquivo `xml` e sim passando o `xml` em formato de `string`:

```
tree = ET.parse(response)
```

Porém não quero ter que salvar essa `string` como arquivo `xml` para depois fazer o `parse` e manipular o arquivo.

Como eu faço para manipular essa `string` como `xml` sem ter q salvá-la como um arquivo em algum diretório?!

Comment: Não vou postar ainda como resposta porque não tenho certeza (e estou sem tempo agora para fazer testes), mas *acho* que dá pra resolver isso usando [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html). Experimente: `import StringIO` e `tree = ET.parse(StringIO.StringIO(respose))`. Mais tarde eu volto aqui. P.S. Na linha logo abaixo está `root = response.getroot()`, não seria `tree.getroot()`?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Sim é `tree.getroot()`, ja fiz a correção :p

Comment: @mgibsonbr Consegui resolver com o `StringIO`. Obrigado :D

Comment: Nesse caso, então, estou postando como resposta. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muitas bibliotecas do Python esperam arquivos ou "*file-likes*" como parâmetros. Embora isso possa parecer restritivo, há um *built-in* específico para se tratar strings como se fossem arquivos: o [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) (ou sua implementação alternativa, `cStringIO`).

```
from StringIO import StringIO
tree = ET.parse(StringIO(response))
```

Explicando: `StringIO(string)` cria um "*file-like*" (i.e. objeto que se comporta como se fosse um arquivo) cujo "conteúdo" é a string passada como argumento. Esse objeto implementa toda a interface de um arquivo, com métodos para abrir, ler, escrever, etc. Passando-se esse objeto para `ET.parse` permite-se que ele o "abra" e "leia" normalmente, acessando seu conteúdo sem a necessidade de se criar um arquivo intermediário.

Comment: Só adicionando - no Python 3 o que antes estava em StringIO.StringIO (e cStrincIO.StringIO) agora está em "io.BytesIO"

Comment: @jsbueno Isso quer dizer que em Python 3 seria necessário codificar a string (que é unicode por padrão nessa versão) em um encoding qualquer, em vez de usá-la como está? (ineficiente, mas pensando melhor, a princípio eu teria que fazer isso também no Python 2...) Vi [nessa documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) que o Python 3 ainda dá suporte a `StringIO` - a menos é claro que a semântica dele tenha mudado e ele não seja mais compatível com os métodos que esperam um *file-like*... Por acaso você teria alguma referência onde eu possa ler mais sobre o assunto?

Comment: Se você tem uma string em Python 3 você tem texto - texto não pode ser lido ou escrito em um arquivo - você _tem_ que codifica-lo com uma codificação. Por favor, leia http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!) para seu próprio bem. O StringIO do Python3 também trabalah com texto - e te dá um buffer de texto - que teria que ser codificado se fosse gravado em disco, ou qualquer outra coisa.

Comment: @jsbueno Estou ciente das questões de encoding. O que eu questionei é que é desnecessário se converter uma string grande para binário e vice-versa, quando se poderia simplesmente "decorar" o StringIO para se comportar como um arquivo em um encoding específico (i.e. fazendo a conversão `char -> bytes` sob demanda, em vez de se converter o texto inteiro e desperdiçar um monte de memória). Pensei que *talvez* o Python 3 tivesse algo assim *built-in*. Da forma como eu vejo, isso é um passo pra trás. Mas de novo, percebo que a situação no Python 2 não é muito melhor que isso...